# Triggering Animations in PowerPoint with Data from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

**Background Info**

*Software used: PowerPoint Mac 2011, Excel Mac 2011*

I'm looking to create a totally self-updating PowerPoint presentation. To this end, I've created a macro-enabled Excel document that updates itself every 30 seconds with the following code:

```
Sub clock()
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1").Value = "Off" Then Exit Sub
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 30), "clock"
End Sub‹
```

The Excel document pulls data from the web using Excel's *External Data Sources* feature, which is then passed through some formulas and arranged into a table. This table is copied to the clipboard and pasted to PowerPoint using *Paste Special* to indicate that is is a *Microsoft Excel Worksheet (code) Object*. The presentation is then saved as a macro-enabled PowerPoint. This creates a presentation containing a table that updates itself automatically.

**Question**

What I want to know is how - or if it's possible - to write a macro to trigger animations in the PowerPoint using data from an embedded Excel table.

For example, if a cell displays 0, a shape would activate a *Fill Color* effect that changes its color to red. If that same cell displays 1, that shape would activate another *Fill Color* effect that changes its color to blue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you link a table from PowerPoint to Excel, the link also picks up conditional formatting. This worked in the files I tested but that is on a PC running Windows 2010 with Excel and PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Which is fine, but what I'm looking to do is use the input from the linked table to trigger actions and animations within the PowerPoint presentation.